# How to hash a class or function definition?

Tags: python, fingerprinting, function-definition

#### Background

When experimenting with machine learning, I often reuse models trained previously, by means of pickling/unpickling.
However, when working on the feature-extraction part, it's a challenge not to confuse different models.
Therefore, I want to add a check that ensures that the model was trained using exactly the same feature-extraction procedure as the test data.

#### Problem

My idea was the following:
Along with the model, I'd include in the pickle dump a hash value which fingerprints the feature-extraction procedure.

When training a model or using it for prediction/testing, the model wrapper is given a feature-extraction class that conforms to certain protocol.
Using `hash()` on that class won't work, of course, as it isn't persistent across calls.
So I thought I could maybe find the source file where the class is defined, and get a hash value from that file.

However, there might be a way to get a stable hash value from the class’s in-memory contents directly.
This would have two advantages:
It would also work if no source file can be found.
And it would probably ignore irrelevant changes to the source file (eg. fixing a typo in the module docstring).
Do classes have a code object that could be used here?

Comment: It’s impossible to prove that none of the functions that your methods *call* haven’t changed.  But it’s pretty straightforward to hash the method definitions themselves (at least within one version of Python).  Is that enough?

Comment: Yes, I think that would be pretty good in most cases. I have learned in the meantime that classes don't have a code object, only function objects do. So for the class hash one would need to iterate over the method hashes.

Comment: They have a code object, but it’s executed and discarded when the class is created (much like a module’s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you’re looking for is a hash procedure that includes all the salient details of the class’s definition.  (Base classes can be included by including *their* definitions recursively.)  To minimize false matches, the basic idea is to apply a wide (cryptographic) hash to a **serialization** of your class.  So start with `pickle`: it supports more types than `hash` and, when it uses identity, it uses a *reproducible* identity based on name.  This makes it a good candidate for the base case of a recursive strategy: deal with the functions and classes whose *contents* are important and let it handle any ancillary objects referenced.

So define a serialization by cases.  Call an object *special* if it falls under any case below but the last.

- For a `tuple` deemed to contain special objects:

  1. The character `t`
  2. The serialization of its `len`
  3. The serialization of each element, in order
- For a `dict` deemed to contain special objects:

  1. The character `d`
  2. The serialization of its `len`
  3. The serialization of each name and value, in sorted order
- For a class whose definition is salient:

  1. The character `C`
  2. The serialization of its `__bases__`
  3. The serialization of its `vars`
- For a function whose definition is salient:

  1. The character `f`
  2. The serialization of its `__defaults__`
  3. The serialization of its `__kwdefaults__` (in Python 3)
  4. The serialization of its `__closure__` (but with cell *values* instead of the cells themselves)
  5. The serialization of its `vars`
  6. The serialization of its `__code__`
- For a code object (since `pickle` doesn’t support them at all):

  1. The character `c`
  2. The serializations of its `co_argcount`, `co_nlocals`, `co_flags`, `co_code`, `co_consts`, `co_names`, `co_freevars`, and `co_cellvars`, in that order; none of these are ever special
- For a static or class method object:

  1. The character `s` or `m`
  2. The serialization of its `__func__`
- For a property:

  1. The character `p`
  2. The serializations of its `fget`, `fset`, and `fdel`, in that order
- For any other object: `pickle.dumps(x,-1)`

(You never actually **store** all this: just create a `hashlib` object of your choice in the top-level function, and in the recursive part `update` it with each piece of the serialization in turn.)

The type tags are to avoid collisions and in particular to be prefix-free.  Binary pickles are already prefix-free.  You can base the decision about a container on a deterministic analysis of its contents (even if heuristic) or on context, so long as you’re consistent.

As always, there is something of an art to balancing false positives against false negatives: for a function, you could include `__globals__` (with pruning of objects already serialized to avoid large if not infinite serializations) or just any `__name__` found therein.  Omitting `co_varnames` ignores renaming local variables, which is good unless introspection is important; similarly for `co_filename` and `co_name`.

You may need to support more types: look for static attributes and default arguments that don’t `pickle` correctly (because they *contain* references to special types) or at all.  Note of course that some types (like file objects) are unpicklable *because* it’s difficult or impossible to serialize them (although unlike `pickle` you can handle lambdas just like any other function once you’ve done `code` objects).  At some risk of false matches, you can choose to serialize just the *type* of such objects (as always, prefixed with a character `?` to distinguish from actually having the type in that position).

Comment: This can catch changes in a function body, but it won't catch changes in any code outside the function that the function relies on. If it tries to serialize `def f(thing): return other_function(thing) - 1` and `other_function` gets completely overhauled, this serialization scheme won't notice.

Comment: @user2357112: Of course, and it won’t catch that the function’s behavior depends on the system clock either.  I already asked about the general impossibility in a comment on the question, and you *can* branch out into `__globals__` to at least catch helpers in the same module if it’s a concern.

Comment: Thanks for the well-structured and -explained instructions. As you say, the hardest part is figuring out what to include, in the trade-off of avoiding false matches vs. rendering the complete process useless by always generating a different hash value.