# Why Python's defaultdict behaves weirdly with pickle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, pickle, defaultdict

I am using PySpark which uses Python's *pickle* to serialize objects. My use case has a nested `defaultdict` data structure like:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

nested_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int)))
```

Pickling this `nested` `defaultdict` structure gives

> PicklingError: Can't pickle  at 0x1076cc9d8>: attribute lookup  on __main__ failed

There's a [wonderful workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16439720/2436425) in an SO answer for that.

I have been trying that and wondering at some unintuitive functionality/usage that it leads to. For example,

```py
import pickle

def dd():
    def di():
        return defaultdict(int)
    return defaultdict(di)

nested = defaultdict(dd)
pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(nested))
```

works but following doesn't work

```py
def nested_dd():
    def dd():
        def di():
            return defaultdict(int)
        return defaultdict(di)
    return defaultdict(dd)

pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(nested_dd()))
```

It gives

> AttributeError: Can't pickle local object `nested_dd.<locals>.dd`

What's happening here?

Comment: Try with `pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(nested_dd))` instead `pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(nested_dd()))`

Comment: @shaikmoeed: no change. Any way what I want is a 3-level deep defaultdict, so I'll be instantiating a `nested_dd` anyway. When I try `nested_dd3 = nested_dd()` I get the same error.

Answer (score 4):

While [other serialization techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52685427/8586227) exist, you can `pickle` only functions that can be found by `from … import foo` (because that’s what unpickling a function *does*).  Your “working” example will fail if the outer `defaultdict` isn’t empty, since each nested dictionary would have a local function as *its* default factory.

In this case, since none of these functions close over anything, you can just write them at top level.

Answer (score 0):

There is another very simple workaround that may suit your use case and I have not seen in any answer. The only caveat is that you lose the default values if you keep expanding the dict after the pickle. Simply do:

```
pickle.dump(dict(nested_dict))
```